# How to get text inside opening tag and change in in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

For example I have `<img onclick="remClicked(this)" src="~/images/chrest.png" />`

I want to change `onclick="remClicked(this)" src="~/images/chrest.png"` on other text by using javascript or jquery.

Is it possible?Something like `document.getElementsByTagName('img').innerHTML = "bla bla bla";`

I know about `$("img").attr("src","x");` but I need something more powerful.

Comment: Your question is unclear. More powerful , You can use `$("img").replaceWith('<img src="~/images/chrest.png2">')`

Comment: More powerful , You can use a screwdrive

Comment: @madalin ivascu: A crowbar is the tool of choice for those things :)

Comment: I need something like $("img").replace("src="~/images/chrest.png2">'),not $("img").replaceWith('<img src="~/images/chrest.png2">')

Comment: document.querySelector('img').src = '~/images/chrest.png2'

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.
may this help you...

```js
function change(){
  document.getElementById('imgId').setAttribute("src", "http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/12413941/3/stock-illustration-12413941-check-mark.jpg");
  document.getElementById('imgId').setAttribute("onClick","myFunction();");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>change</title>
</head>
<body>
<img onClick="org();" id="imgId" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/70/70206.png" alt="hi">
<br><br>
<button onclick="change()">Change onClick & src</button>

</body>
</html>
```